# How to monitor incoming/outgoing traffic on windows mobile?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, network-traffic

I want to check how much was sent/received by WM phone over GPRS/wifi. Please suggest a freeware utility for this or the way i can manage it in .NET CF. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rhapsody, thank you for the answer(LCMinutes is not the program i needed), but i've found what i was looking for:
 
http://www.drews-informatik.de/softwareprojekte/pocket-pc/ppcinterfacemonitor
 Tho still don't know how to do it with code.

Comment: To figure out how to do this with code, you can take the PPC Interface Monitor executable and put it in .NET Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

With Reflector you can disassemble .NET assemblies. :)

Comment: :)) forgot about reflector! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Check this site: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=218663 and especially [LCMinutes](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=354103)